# Looping Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

My friend and I are working on a game. It's a simple text-based game sort of like Oregon Trail. You press a key to do different things and then press a key to go to the next turn, which is where the problems arise. Pressing next turn reruns the whole turn function. But on the second turn, everything will be repeated twice; then four times; then eight; etc.

```
<html>
<script>
function game() {

document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 50){
alert('you took your turn')

 }else if (event.keyCode == 49) {
    alert('Proceeding to next turn.');
    game()
  }
});
}

</script>
<button onclick="game()">game</button>
</html>
```

We're very inexperienced and we can't figure out how to stop it from looping. What's the issue with the code.

Comment: Everytime key '49' is pressed, you re-run `game()`, which attaches a new event listener.  Why does `game` call itself?

Comment: You're adding a new event listener every time your function is executed, which is every time the button is clicked and every time `1` is entered from within the event listener itself. You just need to add the event listener once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are subscribing to `keypress` event each time you call the function `game()`:

It seems that you don't need to call `game()` inside the keypress subscription. If you remove it, the behavior described will disappear.

Moreover, you should subscribe to the keypress event only once. So, you should verify if you already had subscribed to it:

```
<html>
<script>
let subscribeEvent; 
function game() {
 if(subscribeEvent) {
   document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 50){
     alert('you took your turn')

     } else if (event.keyCode == 49) {
        alert('Proceeding to next turn.');
     }
  });
 }
}

</script>
<button onclick="game()">game</button>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `game()` function from the else if statement, then it should work out. The recursion is happening because every time the button is clicked, a new event listener gets paired/attached to game().

**Note:** EventListeners listen for events until they are remove.